# Make DIV to fill table cell

Tags: html, css

I'd like a DIV inside table cell fit all available space wide.

[image]

There are two DIVs in green cell: first one has `margin-left: 40px` and second **Pencil** have width 100%. I want latter DIV to take free space like this:

[image]

I think that problem is that 100% of width for Pencil's block is actually it's parent width, i.e. green cell. As there's also left yellow box with some width and margin, content of the cell is overflowed and splitted into two "rows". Unfortunately,

I can't find a way to acheive desired layout with CSS only without JavaScript. Is it possible at all?

Let me share a live example to play with: [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/leyijaqefe/edit?html,css,output). Thank you in advance!

Comment: try to set some padding. Hope this will help.

Comment: @NomanJaved, could you explain your suggestion a little, please?

Comment: try this. div.left
      div.handler.offset [+]
      title Pencil in the JS Bin

Comment: Based on the JS Bin, this is really a series of DIVs that you're forcing to act like a table. Is there a reason why you wouldn't just build this with an actual table instead?

Comment: @Angelique well, full solution (not a JS Bin example) isn't a table by semantics, so I worry it wouldn't be nice to use actual table there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>If you set the `div.title` like this it will work</strike>

```
width: calc(100% - 50px); // This one
```

Adjust the "50px" to be more accurate to the space the `div.handler` occupy.

---

Update based on comment about supporting IE8

By changing to this in your JSBin, it works

```
.left {
  .border(green);
  width: @width-left;
  overflow: hidden;

  & > * {
  }

  .handler {
    .border(magenta);
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 20px;
    float: left;
  }

  .title {
    .border(red);
    overflow: hidden;
  }

}
```

Sample snippet

```css
.table {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  display: table;
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.table .row {
  display: table-row;
}
.table .row > * {
  display: table-cell;
}
.table .row .left {
  border: 1px dotted green;
  width: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table .row .left .handler {
  border: 1px dotted magenta;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.table .row .left .title {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table .row .right {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  width: 60%;
}
.table .row .right > * {
  display: inline-block;
}
.table .offset {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="handler offset">[+]</div>
      <div class="title">Pencil</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="price">$0.60</div>
      <div class="quantity">14 PCS</div>
      <div class="total">$8.40</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I wish I could use `calc()` function, but this one have to be compatible with IE8.

Comment: unfortunately I can't get it working: `.title` width is set to content and not expanding to the rest of the cell.

Comment: @Yaruson Updated .. now it should work for you .. [Updated JSBin](https://jsbin.com/jaleligoqe/2/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

```
.table .row .left .handler,
.table .row .left .title {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I also had to set `display: table-row` for `.left` class to get it working. Is it OK?

Comment: [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com) accepts **code-only answer** like this, but it isn't *very* help for others. Please [edit] your answer and explain *How does your code work*. Sometimes, also *Why doesn't OP's code work*.

Comment: @Yaruson, for your jsbin it works with just these two. If you need some other changes in the full code, it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer really depends on how you want text overflow to be handled - but if you just change .title to have display:inline (rather than inline-block) then it seems to render as you want. However, this might not be the desired result when you have text in the cell much longer than the word "Pencil".